# Prove that $ \sin (\pi x) \leq 4x (1-x) $ for all non negative $ x \leq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am interested in a method which uses appropriate mean value theorems. I tried Cauchys mean value theorem but failed. Any help would be appreciated.

Please note:I am not looking for an answer which uses derivates, only mean value theorems (of course, MVTs include derivatives, but I want to solve this question as an application of a MVT)

Comment: "not derivaties, only mean value theorems" Well, (most) mean value theorems involve derivatives, no?

Comment: @leonbloy I think he means don't use derivatives to find a maximum/minimum to solve the problem

Comment: @leonbloy I have edited the question

Comment: If a differential approach is forbidden, then what is the definition of the sine ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust can you tell me why it matters?

Comment: We can't work on an undefined function.

Comment: This video may be of value...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dO4zbUTcf_M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to consider $x\le \frac12$, because for $x>\frac12$ we can use $\sin \pi x = \sin(\pi(1-x))$.

Let us substitute $t = \frac12-x$. 
\begin{align} \sin \pi x &= \sin (\frac{\pi}{2} - \pi t) = \cos \pi t = 1 - 2\sin^2\frac{\pi t}{2}\end{align}
Since $\sin y$ is a concave function on the interval $y\in[0,\pi/4]$ (a fact that you can prove using the MVT, if you want), we have
$$ \sin y \ge \frac{y \sin \frac{\pi}{4} + (\frac{\pi}{4}-y) \sin 0}{\frac{\pi}{4}} = \frac{2\sqrt{2}y}{\pi} $$
Using this inequality we get
$$\sin\pi x \le 1 - 2(\sqrt{2}t)^2 = 1-4t^2 = 4x(1-x) $$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\sin(\pi x)\le4x(1-x)\text{ for }x\in[0,1]
&\iff\cos(\pi x)\le1-4x^2\text{ for }x\in\left[-\tfrac12,\tfrac12\right]\tag1\\
&\iff\cos(\pi x)\le1-4x^2\text{ for }x\in\left[\,0,\tfrac12\,\right]\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto\frac12-x$
$(2)$: both sides of the inequality are even

---

For $x\in\left[\,0,\frac12\,\right]$, consider
$$
f(x)=4x^2+\cos(\pi x)\tag3
$$
$f(0)=1$, $f'(0)=0$ and
$$
f''(x)=8-\pi^2\cos(\pi x)\tag4
$$
$f''(x)\le0$ for $0\le x\le x_0=\frac1\pi\cos^{-1}\left(\frac8{\pi^2}\right)$. The Mean Value Theorem, applied once, says that $f'(x)\le0$ for $0\le x\le x_0$; and applied twice, says that
$$
f(x)\le1\text{ for }0\le x\le x_0\tag5
$$
$f''(x)\ge0$ for $x_0\le x\le\frac12$; that is, $f$ is convex on $\left[\,x_0,\frac12\,\right]$. Since $f(x_0)\le1$ and $f\!\left(\frac12\right)=1$, we know that $$
f(x)\le1\text{ for }x_0\le x\le\tfrac12\tag6
$$
$(2)$ is satisfied by $(5)$ and $(6)$.